# How to get a list of objects that inherits the same interface?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Let's say I have an interface called `ICar` and it is implemented by two classes; `BMW` and `Audi`. They contain the name and the content (visualisation of the car). I want to get the names "BMW" and "Audi" and listed them in Combo Box. So once the user selects the name the object content should appear. This what I've done so far.

```
interface ICar{
    String Name {get;}
    object Content{get;}
}
```

It is inherited by two classes, `Audi` and `BMW`.

```
class Audi : ICar{
    AudiCar audi = new AudiCar();

    String Name{get {return"Audi";}}
    object Content{get {return audi;}}
}


class BMW : ICar{
    BMWCar bmw = new BMWCar();

    String Name{get {return"BMW";}}
    object Content{get {return bmw;}}
}
```

`BMWCar` and `AudiCar` have the visualisation of BMW and Audi car.

In `MainModel` class,

```
Class MainModel{
    List<ICar> cars;
    ICar selectedCar;

    MainModel(IEnumerable<ICar> cars){
        this.cars = new List<ICar>(cars);
        this.selectedCar = this.cars.FirstOrDefault();
    } 

    IList<ICar> Cars {get{return this.cars;}}

    public object Car{
        get{ return this.selectedCar.Content;}
    }
}
```

In the XAML,

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCar, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

But I'm not getting the two values "Audi" and "BMW" inside the combo box. Please tell if I've done something wrong.

Comment: Dont know about the answer but im not sure you can provide fields within an interface (C# 5?) so the best practice first is to have an Abstract class called Car.

Comment: Sidenote: use also an interface for Content

Comment: @OriRefael C# interfaces do allow properties to be defined. Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754274/interface-class-with-getter-and-setter-in-c-sharp

Comment: @Giggity for my opinion its the wrong way to use interfaces...especially in this case.

Comment: @OriRefael Sir, why you think it's wrong? Can you please explain it to me

Comment: What values are you getting in your dropdown?

Comment: Name is not a public property ( get ). SelectedCar is not a not a public property. What you trying to do is just strange. You will never have two BMW?

Comment: Your code is fine. It shows Audi, BMW in the list. Make sure you are passing something in the ctor.

Comment: @DavidG I'm not getting any value. Once I debugged it shows `IList<ICar> Cars {get{return this.cars;}}` this.cars null

Comment: @AnjumSKhan Is it getting the" Name" from the two classes? What did you do in the main? I tried to call but the default constructor which has no args is executing and I tried to chain the two constructors by using this(); in the constructor with args. But it says method name expected. Please tell me how you got it to work.

Comment: Pass properly initialized list into ctor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a list of classes which implement an interface:

- Determine which assembly you're going to look in for types that implement `ICar`
- Get all of the types in that assembly
- Determine which of those types implement `ICar`.

Here's an example. For demonstration I'm looking for classes in the same assembly as the interface (`ICar`).

```
var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof (ICar));
var typesInAssembly = assembly.GetTypes();
var matching = typesInAssembly
    .Where(type => typeof(ICar).IsAssignableFrom(type) && !type.IsInterface);
// Checking !type.IsInterface or else it also returns ICar.
```

Answer (score 0):

please use observableCollection instead of List.

```
Class MainModel{
    List<ICar> cars;
    ICar selectedCar;

    ShowData(IEnumerable<ICar> cars){
        foreach (var car in cars)
            {
                _car.Add(car);
            }
        this.selectedCar = this.cars.FirstOrDefault();
    } 

     private ObservableCollection<Car> _cars=new ObservableCollection<Car>();

        public ObservableCollection<Car> Cars
        {
            get { return _cars; }
            set { _cars= value; }
        }
    public object Car{
        get{ return this.selectedCar.Content;}
    }
}
```